# Isomorphism of elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, change-of-variable

One of the first things discussed in books on elliptic curves is the change of variables that "puts the curve" in Weierstrass form. To give a concrete example, the curve $6y^2=2x^3+3x^2+x$ (the "cannonball problem" discussed at the beginning of L. Washington's book) can be put in Weierstrass form $v^2=u^3-\frac{9}{4}u$  by the change of variable $(u,v)=(3x+\frac{3}{2},9y)$. In fact, the explicit formulas to define the group law is usually only given for the Weierstrass form, with the understanding that one can always reduce the more general form to it (assuming the characteristic of the field is not 2 or 3). My question is about the precise meaning of "puts the curve" above. The two curves are surely not "isomorphic", as defined for example in http://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/ec.isomorphism

I understand that of course studying and deriving properties of the simpler curve $v^2=u^3-\frac{9}{4}u$ one can easily go back to the original curve $6y^2=2x^3+3x^2+x$ using the simple transformation, but it seems to me that a discussion about the relationship between the two curves would be helpful. But I did not find it in any of the standard references on elliptic curves I know. To put my question in simple minded terms, what happens to the elliptic curve when we make a change of variables? Because one thinks of two curves as being "the same" if they are isomorphic, but apparently the first thing one does when studying an elliptic curve is to change it to another one that is not "the same".

Comment: Why are they "surely not" isomorphic as defined in your reference? On a more basic level; note that the change of variables yields a bijection between the rational points of the two curves.

Comment: The definition of isomorphism between two elliptic curves is that there should be a bijective rational function that is also a group isomorphism. This is a very restrictive condition. In case of elliptic curves over $\mathbb C$ (or any algebraically closed field) in Weierstrass form $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$, the only such rational functions are of the form $f(x,y)=(u^2x,u^3y)$ for some element $u$ of the field (see for example Proposition III.1.4(b) of Silverman's book "The arithmetic of elliptic curves". The transformation $f(x,y)=\left(3x+\frac{3}{2}, 9y\right)$ is not of this form.

Comment: The group operation on an elliptic curve also has a geometric interpretation; it is a matter of drawing and intersecting some lines. This is preserved by affine transformations, and in particular by your linear change of variables.

Comment: And I haven't taken up Silverman's book, but it seems that the rational functions of the form $f(x,y)=(u^2x,u^3y)$ are precisely those that preserve Weierstrass form. Your original curve is not in Weierstrass form.

Comment: Yes, you are right and your comment was quite helpful. I have now figured out a few more facts, but still have a question. I will edit my original post.

Comment: I suggest you revert the edit and ask a new question, as your edit introduces an entirely new question.

Comment: Also, it is no t true that every isogeny is given by a linear transformation. Of course every (invertible) linear transformation does define an isogeny.

Comment: I did as you suggested (deleted the edit and asked a new question).

Comment: About the isogeny: I was quoting from Silverman's book that every isomorphism between elliptic curves (in generalized Weierstrass form) must be a linear transformation of that type. I think I do not understand the difference between isogeny and isomorphism. An example would be helpful.

Comment: I don’t see isogenies coming up here. Perhaps if you want an example of an isogeny that isn’t an isomorphism, you could ask a new question. Suffice it to say here that a nonisomorphic isogeny will have a nontrivial kernel, so that $(x,y)\mapsto$ (something with nonconstant functions in denominator).

Comment: Am I right then in understanding that an invertible isogeny between two elliptic curves (in generalized Weierstrass form) is the same thing as an isomorphism between the two elliptic curves?

Comment: Yes, an isogeny with trivial kernel is an isomorphism.